# How to pass the values from View to Controller using ajax method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application.

I want  pass the values from list to the controller,

The below code is to display the list of Products ...it shows perfectly.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmCreate" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)   
    <div class="row-fluid">   
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Section Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProductList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td >@item.SectionName</td>
                        <td >@item.Quantity</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span class="span12 alert alert-success" id="status-message" style="margin-bottom:10px;"><strong>Your Order has been sent to HO  sucessfully.</strong><a href="#" id="CheckOrder" onclick="submitForm()" style="font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;margin-right:10px;">Clcik Here </a> to check status. Please click on back button to view list.</span>
    }
```

Now, on when I click on the above link, I want to pass the data to the method in controller.

I have written the below code, It calls the method of controller but the list doesn't contain any items. It shows the null value. how to pass the list using ajax ?

Whats wrong in code ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#CheckOrder').click(function(){ 
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("DATACoME")' + '?List=@ViewBag.ProductList'
             }).done(function(){
                 //do something
             });
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {


     $('#CheckOrder').click(function(){ 
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("DATACoME")',
             data: {parameterNameFromTheController: '@ViewBag.ProductList'}
         }).done(function(){
             //do something
         });

     });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what data type I should write in the method ?

Comment: `ProductList` contains what data?